# Getting Facebook Profile Picture from user ID

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, sdk

**Scenario:** 
I have obtained **Facebook user ID's** of the people who have liked my certain POST (status) of my Facebook Page.

**Question:**
How should I be able to get their profile picture or link to their profile picture. Size of the picture doesn't matter.

PS: I am using PHP GraphAPI SDK

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using PHP GraphAPI SDK you should update the code accordingly, just replace the `{facebookid}` with the id of user you want the picture.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/{facebookid}/picture',
  array (
    'redirect' => false,
    'height' => 200,
    'width' => 200,
    'type' => 'normal',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I have tested your code. It gives us the URL of the profile picture. God Bless You and Your Skills :)

Comment: @MikhailTal , if his answer solves your problem then accept it.

Comment: Why the hell is everyone voting down this question ? Is it that bad?

Comment: Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Why so much negativety? Tell me so that I avoid in future.

Comment: I am glad that i was able to help you.
@MikhailTal it is voted down by some users because you haven't try to solve it with your effort if you have researched about it then you would have definitely got it solved without posting here. I hope that clears your confusion.